# load() API call function callback scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I have been coding in JS for a while now, but somehow I always get a bit of a 'scratch head' type of problem. I think that I need to do some digging in, but in the meanwhile can someone help with this one?

**So here is the problem:**
I am passing through the item (got by $(this)) into the callback function. This code does not work - when I really think it should. Since I have placed the $(this) into a variable (cloning the data?) and then passed it into the callback through a function, surely it should not loose the data? But it does, and horribly

```
// Allow hrefs with the class 'ajax' and a rel attribute set with a selector to load via ajax into that selector.
$(".ajax").unbind("click").click
(
    function(e)
    {

        var locationhint = $(this).attr("rel");            
        var $location = $(locationhint);
        $location.html ("<img src='images/blockloading.gif' />");            
        $location.load($(this).attr("href").replace("index.php", "ajax.php"), '', function($location){dready($location);}); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

Now that **doesn't work**.

**This one works:**

```
$(".ajax").unbind("click").click
(
    function(e)
    {             
        $("#myspecificdiv").load($(this).attr("href").replace("index.php", "ajax.php"), '', function(){dready($("#myspecificdiv"));}); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

I take it it's a scope problem, but I have also done this, which *should* work because it's exactly the same as the 'static' one above, essentially, because it's passing the text ID of the element. **This one also breaks:**.

```
$(".ajax").unbind("click").click
(
    function(e)
    {
        var locationhint = $(this).attr("rel");            
        var $location = $(locationhint);
        $location.html ("<img src='images/blockloading.gif' />");  
        var locationid = "#" + $location.attr("id");
        $location.load($(this).attr("href").replace("index.php", "ajax.php"), '', function(locationid){dready($(locationid));});
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

The broken ones, when I console.log locationid, return the internal HTML of the target DIV. $location.attr("id"); can't return raw HTML when there is no call to it anywhere else surely? So it's scope I take it? But then how is it getting the internal HTML to spit out?

Any solutions?

**Update:**
12 seconds after I posted this it occurred to me that function($location){dready($location);} the internal function on the callback might automagically pass the AJAX call response through? But why?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this `function($location){dready($location);}` but you do not need to since the outer scope has $location defined the callback func will understand this var without trying to pass it into the callback funcion so in this instance

`function(){dready($location);}`

will work.

Another way to conquor scoping issues is to use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). This allows you to set the this context under which the function will be called. `jQuery.proxy( dready, $location )` returns a function that can be used as a callback which when invoked will call the method dready with this set to to $location.

e.g

```
$location.load($(this).attr("href").replace("index.php", "ajax.php"), '', jQuery.proxy( dready, $location );});
```